# Write to local Hive metastore instead of AWS Glue Data Catalog when developing a AWS Glue job locally

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm trying to create a local development environment for writing glue jobs and have followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-libraries.html to use the `amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01` docker image.

However in my glue code I also want to pull data from s3 and create a database in a metastore with spark sql eg

```
spark.sql(f'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {database_name}')
```

I have managed to use a local version of aws by using localstack, and configuring hadoop to use my local aws endpoint

```
spark-submit --conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint=localstack:4566 \
\--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider \
\--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key=bar \
\--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key=foo \
\--conf spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access=true
```

However when calling the above spark sql command I'm getting an error as it's trying to use the real aws glue data catalog as a metastore

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to verify existence of default database: com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.AWSGlueException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400
```

I have tried to configure spark to use a local metastore when initialising the spark context, however it still tried to use glue and I get the above error from aws

```
        SparkSession.builder.appName(f"{task}")
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/temp")
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue was that the `aws-glue-libs` image contained a `hive-site.xml` which was referencing the Amazon's hive metastore. To get this to work I removed this as a step in the `Dockerfile`, and specified the full path to the local hive store in the configuration when running a `spark-submit`

My Dockerfile

```
FROM amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01
RUN rm /home/glue_user/spark/conf/hive-site.xml
```

And the conf in spark-submit

```
    --conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/home/glue_user/workspace/temp/db \
    --conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dderby.system.home=/home/glue_user/workspace/temp/hive' \
```